# how to remove multiple row in entire dataset based on its content using python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove multiple rows that contain the word "end" in the switch column. I have tried the following code but I still can't get my desired result. I have attached the head of my Dataframe, the code that I have used and the result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTXya.png)
the Dataframe seems to be empty. any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of posting code as screenshots, please copy and paste your code into the body of your question. Images make it difficult for others to answer your question as images hinder readability and the code is not able to be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I have used small chunk of data as an reference example from your provided image.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = ['end']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2010-11-04' , '2010-11-04', '2010-11-04' , '2010-11-04', '2010-11-04'], 'activity':['S','S','B','B','S'],
...                         'switch':['begin','end','begin','end','begin']})
>>>
>>> print(df)

         date activity switch
0  2010-11-04        S  begin
1  2010-11-04        S    end
2  2010-11-04        B  begin
3  2010-11-04        B    end
4  2010-11-04        S  begin

>>> df[~df['switch'].isin(a)]

         date activity switch
0  2010-11-04        S  begin
2  2010-11-04        B  begin
4  2010-11-04        S  begin
```